# Date Query not working on Google App Engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

```
      Date today = new Date();        
      Query query5 = pm.newQuery(TMS.class);
      query5.setFilter("start_date < date");
      query5.setFilter("end_date > date");
      query5.setFilter("emp_Id == id");
      query5.declareParameters("java.util.Date date,String id");
      List<TMS> result1 = (List<TMS>)query5.execute(today,session.getAttribute("emp_Id").toString());
```

Query gives all the result and the condition is not working.. It is not giving any error also. can any body give the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but maybe it happens because there are some restrictions on queries.

On GAE you can't use inequality filters on more than one property. You use operator LESS_THAN on "start_date" property and operator GREATER_THAN on "end_date" property. Maybe that's the problem.

Check this out: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Restrictions_on_Queries

Comment: But that can be used only on low level datastore where we create Entity.. That is not available for JDO..

Comment: But JDO uses low-level datastore. And that restrictions apply for JDO too.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying on multiple properties.  You will need to create an index by defining it in your datastore.indexes file.  Single property queries are only enabled by default.